# animating a div based on its existing position

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate a div -1500px every time my .btn-arrow button is clicked by grabbing the current position of #content

```
  var $offset = $('#content').offset.left()-1500;
    $('.btn-arrow').click( function(){ 
            $('#content').animate({marginLeft:$offset}); return false;
    });

<div style="margin-left: 0px; width: 99999px;" id="content">content </div>
```

Its not working though currently, any ideas anyone?

Comment: Please paste associated html.

Comment: I've edited the above code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need the correct sytax:

```
 {marginLeft:'-=1500'}
```

(mind the `quotes` and the `-=` that animates **relative** to the current value.

you don't need to use the offset.

but I guess you need :

```
{left:'-=1500'}
```

in this case

[more here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 2):

`offset()` method returns offset object not the actual offset value.

the object returned by `offset()` method has two properties, `left` and `top`

so what you want to do is `$offset.left - 1500`

check the [offset@jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: left is not a method but porperty so you'd need to do element.offset().left rather then element.offset().left()

Answer (score 1):

offset is an object not a value. Access with offset.left and offset.top.